# HTML multiple pages in one with CSS and no JS

Tags: html, css

I've seen some websites that uses CSS to change page without using javascript and they use a hashtag to remember what page the user is viewing.

Example typing the url example.com/#page1 would show you page1 etc.

I've made an example with CSS and javascript, but as mentioned above, I would like to get the same result but with only CSS.

My code:

```
<head>
<style>
#content2 {
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href ="#link1" id="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href ="#link2" id="link2">Link 2</a>

<div id="content1">
Content of page 1 (Link 1)
</div>

<div id="content2">
Content of page 2 (Link 2)
</div>

<script>
var hash = window.location.hash;
// Show a page based on # ( so a user can LINK to a specific page)

//Page 1
if(hash == "#link1") {
$("#content1").css("display","block");
}
$("#link1").click(function() {
$("#content1").show();
$("#content2").hide();
});

//Page2
if(hash == "#link2") {
$("#content2").css("display","block");
}
$("#link2").click(function() {
$("#content2").show();
$("#content1").hide();
});
</script>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dq90d8ry/

Comment: Make use of this: http://webdesignerhut.com/create-pure-css-tabs/ or http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ojtal BTW they are tabbed contents not pages.

Comment: They don't change pages, they scroll to an existing div within the page. So if you have <div id="hey"> clicking on <a href="#hey> will scroll you to that div. However since <a> elements work over paths (unless intrupped by js) they change the url to example.com/#hey

Comment: I guess I want tabs then, but how can you make that user friendly? I want users to be able to link to a specific "tab" without JS if possible.

Comment: Dennis, mess around with that codepen Manoj linked. The answer is in there. The way they do it in that example is stylize some radio button inputs then set style rules based on whether they are checked or not.

Comment: i added a pure css example check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Atarget)  pseudo class:

Let's see an example. (Example extracted from [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/target.en.html#default2))

It has some links and elements with corresponding IDs:

```
<p>
  <a href="#item1">item 1</a>
  <a href="#item2">item 2</a>
  <a href="#item3">item 3</a>
  <a href="#default">clear</a>

<div class="items">
  <p id="item1">... item 1...
  <p id="item2">... item 2...
  <p id="item3">...
  <p id="default"><!-- by default, show no text -->
</div>
```

The style rules first hide all the Ps inside the DIV, but then override that for the P that is the current target:

```
div.items p {display: none}
div.items p:target {display: block}
```

That's all.

Actually, we added ':not(:target)', to assure that only CSS3 browsers will hide the element. So the better rules are these:

```
div.items p:not(:target) {display: none}
div.items p:target {display: block}
```

Comment: I'll check this out. Will this show the user item2 if the user types in example.com/#item2 ?

Comment: Yes. It works. Check the link I provided for w3.org.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Why down vote this post?

Comment: Indeed there are. You should update your answer to include a better example, in case anyone else is looking for this. The most of the code in your answer is on W3 at the moment :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is  a quick jquery example:

Css:

```
#tabs {

width: 100%;
height:30px; 
border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
padding-right: 2px;
margin-top: 30px;


}
a {cursor:pointer;}

#tabs li {
float:left; 
list-style:none; 
border-top:1px solid #ccc; 
border-left:1px solid #ccc; 
border-right:1px solid #ccc; 
margin-right:5px; 
border-top-left-radius:3px;  
border-top-right-radius:3px;
  outline:none;
}

#tabs li a {

font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size: small;
font-weight: bold; 
color: #5685bc;;
   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-left: 7px;
   padding-right: 7px;
padding-bottom: 8px; 
display:block; 
background: #FFF;
border-top-left-radius:3px; 
border-top-right-radius:3px; 
text-decoration:none;
outline:none;

}

#tabs li a.inactive{
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
color:#666666;
background: #EEE;
 outline:none;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;

}

#tabs li a:hover, #tabs li a.inactive:hover {


color: #5685bc;
  outline:none;
}

.container {

clear:both;           
width:100%; 

text-align:left;
  padding-top: 20px;

}

 .container h2 { margin-left: 15px;  margin-right: 15px;  margin-bottom:    10px; color: #5685bc; }

 .container p { margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;  margin-top: 10px;    margin-bottom: 10px; line-height: 1.3; font-size: small; }

.container ul { margin-left: 25px; font-size: small; line-height: 1.4; list-       style-type: disc; }

.container li { padding-bottom: 5px; margin-left: 5px;}

#tab1C {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#tab2C {
font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

HTML & JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><title>Tabbed Structure - Regular</title>
<link href="css/help.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#tabs li a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
$('.container').hide();
$('.container:first').show();

$('#tabs li a').click(function(){
var t = $(this).attr('id');
   if($(this).hasClass('inactive')){ //this is the start of our condition
$('#tabs li a').addClass('inactive');
$(this).removeClass('inactive');

$('.container').hide();
$('#'+ t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
   }
  });

  });

  </script>
  </head>


  <body>
  <ul id="tabs">

  <li><a id="tab1">Tab1</a></li>
  <li><a id="tab2">tab2</a></li>
  <li><a id="tab3">tab3</a></li>
  <li><a id="tab4">tab4</a></li>

    </ul>
      <div class="container" id="tab1C">
         this is tab1 so
      </div>
      <div class="container" id="tab2C">
        this is tab2 so
      </div>
      <div class="container" id="tab3C">this is tab3 so</div>
      <div class="container" id="tab4C">this is tab4 so</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

There is some quick code to help you on some jQuery, CSS and html tabs

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't want to use JS if possible

Comment: I saw your edit, It is a good answer but still using Javascript

Comment: @DennisEnström i added another one

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure css example:

HTML:

```
<h1>Pure CSS Tabs <span>Just CSS, No JS!</span></h1>
<ul class="tabs">
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
    <label for="tab1">Description</label>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do     eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim     veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum     dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,     sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        </div>
        </li>

    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
    <label for="tab2">Specification</label>
    <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
      <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem     accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo     inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia     consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci     velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla?</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<br style="clear: both;" />

<p class="link">See the <a href="http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/IGxim">3D Box</a> demo!</p>
```

CSS:

```
@import "compass/css3";

@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato");

$background: #9b59b6;
$tabs-base-color: #8e44ad;
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Lato;
  color: #fff; 
  background: $background;  
}
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 0 100px 10px; 
  span { 
    font-size: 13px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 4px;
  }
}
.tabs {
  width: 650px;  
  float: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px 0 0 10px;
  text-align: left;
  li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
  input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }
  label {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 21px;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: $tabs-base-color;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px; 
    @include transition(all 0.2s ease-in-out);
    &:hover {
      background: darken($tabs-base-color, 10);
    }
  }
  .tab-content{
    z-index: 2;
    display: none; 
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 25px;  
    position: absolute;
    top: 53px;
    left: 0; 
    background: darken($tabs-base-color, 15);
  }
  //The Magic
  [id^="tab"]:checked + label { 
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 17px; 
    background: darken($tabs-base-color, 15); 
  }
  [id^="tab"]:checked ~ [id^="tab-content"] {
    display: block;
  }
}
p.link {
  clear: both;
  margin: 380px 0 0 15px;
  a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 5px;
        background-color: darken($tabs-base-color, 15);
    @include transition(all 0.2s ease-in);
    &:hover {
      background-color: darken($tabs-base-color, 20);
    }
  }
}
```

this code is from: http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ojtal